# Webdriver setup error in Eclipse, Mac OS X Catalina

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, eclipse, firefoxdriver

After upgrading Mac OS X to Catalina, I have been trying to execute a very basic script written in Java for Firefox in Eclipse IDE 2018.
I've installed Gecko driver already through terminal and it's placed in `/usr/local/bin.`

Although, I've put the path in the script,  `System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");`

it keeps showing me **error** that `Webdriver driver = new firefoxDriver`  cannot be resolved.

**CODE:**

```
package newproject; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
public class PG1 { 
public static void main(String[] args{
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/usr/local/bin/geckodriver"); 
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
String baseUrl =  "http://demo.test.com/test/newtours/"; String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours"; 
String actualTitle = ""; // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL driver.get(baseUrl);
 // get the actual value of the title 
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();  (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){ System.out.println("Test Passed!"); } 
else { System.out.println("Test Failed"); } 
//close Fire fox driver.close(); } }
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Could you post the code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package newproject; import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver; 
public class PG1 { 
public static void main(String[] args) 
{   System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");        
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();              String baseUrl =  "http://demo.test.com/test/newtours/"; String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours"; 
String actualTitle = ""; // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL driver.get(baseUrl);
 // get the actual value of the title 
actualTitle = driver.getTitle();  (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){ System.out.println("Test Passed!"); } 
else { System.out.println("Test Failed"); } 
//close Fire fox driver.close(); } }
```

Comment: Hi Prome, I deleted your comment by mistake. Here's the code.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30895)

Comment: I'll take care of this, thanks for pointing it out. Nithin.

Comment: updated the question with your code. Answer would probably gets deleted by Admin soon as it was EDIT of your own question.

Comment: Thanks so much Bharat!